# Handling autocompletion in text boxes. differently from pressing enter

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

When AutoCompleteCustomSource property of Windows.Forms.TextBox is set, list of variants appears during the entering in textbox.
One can either use a mouse to point and click on one of the variants or choose with up-down buttons and press Enter.
You can also press enter whenever you like.

The gist of a problem is, when the selection with mouse is made, KeyDown (KeyUp, KeyPress) event(s) is(are) raised exactly as if an Enter key was pressed on the keyboard.
How can i determine what really happened and handle selection using mouse curor and press of the Enter key differently?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by tracking mouse and keyboard events of the text box. The resulting functionality was similar to the browser address bar. I can't get to the source code right now but it was basic logic around MouseDown, MouseUp, KeyDown, KeyUp whilue storing their values in variables.

Comment: Please, dig up the details. I've tried trcking those events, but no mouse events (MouseUp, MouseDown,MouseClick) are being generated by the textbox when one clicks on the autosuggestions list.

Comment: Where do those mouse events go is somewhat of a mystery to me. Quite possibly they are consumed by the temporary visible list control (that as far as i am aware we can exercise no control over).